# Neater way to match array for classes of elements with rspec?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I wanted to assert on classes of elements an array contained, and I tried the following ways:

This doesn't work, but it looks nice and readable:

```
["String", :symbol, Object.new].should =~ [an_instance_of(String), an_instance_of(Symbol), an_instance_of(Object)]
```

but gives me following error:

```
Failure/Error: ["String", :symbol, Object.new].should =~ [an_instance_of(String), an_instance_of(Symbol), an_instance_of(Object)]
   expected collection contained:  [#<RSpec::Mocks::ArgumentMatchers::InstanceOf:0x007f9e6a33dbe0 @klass=String>, #<RSpec::Mocks::ArgumentMatchers::InstanceOf:0x007f9e6a33dbb8 @klass=Symbol>, #<RSpec::Mocks::ArgumentMatchers::InstanceOf:0x007f9e6a33db68 @klass=Object>]
   actual collection contained:    ["String", :symbol, #<Object:0x007f9e6a33dca8>]
   the extra elements were:        ["String", :symbol, #<Object:0x007f9e6a33dca8>]
```

Note that there are no missing elements.

This works, but looks hacky:

```
["String", :symbol, Object.new].collect{|x| x.class}.should =~ [String, Symbol,Object]
```

1. Is there a better way to assert the same thing?
2. Why are there no Missing elements the first way?

Answer (score 3):

You could use `&:class` instead of a block,

```
["String",:symbol,Object.new].map(&:class).should =~ [String,Symbol,Object]
```

which yields the same but is more readable.

Also, I used `map` which is a short alias for the `collect` method.

Comment: nice.. much better :)
But this only answers the first question.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the second part is down to your assertion "Note that there are no missing elements." There *are* missing elements.

This:

```
expected collection contained:  [#<RSpec::Mocks::ArgumentMatchers::InstanceOf:0x007f9e6a33dbe0 @klass=String>, #<RSpec::Mocks::ArgumentMatchers::InstanceOf:0x007f9e6a33dbb8 @klass=Symbol>, #<RSpec::Mocks::ArgumentMatchers::InstanceOf:0x007f9e6a33db68 @klass=Object>]
```

is not the same as this:

```
the extra elements were:        ["String", :symbol, #<Object:0x007f9e6a33dca8>]
```

The first contains mock objects of instances of a class, the second contains instances of classes. The `instance_of` matcher is not supposed to be used in this way, would you do this?

```
["String", :symbol, Object.new].should =~ [respond_to(:gsub), respond_to(:intern), respond_to(:object_id)]
```

It doesn't make sense because you should either be testing the *array* **or** that the contents of the array *each have some kind of attribute*. What you've done is to mix up the two tests, and in doing that caused problems with both.

```
subject { instance }
["String", :symbol, Object.new].each do |thing|
  let(:instance) { thing.class }
    if instance.class == String
      it{ should respond_to(:gsub) }
    else #...
```

something more like that, but I think this is a code/design smell anyway - why would you have such different things in the same array? It's difficult to spec, to test, and to handle.